# Aramex Shipping and Tracking Extension

Tags: shipping

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aramex-shipping-and-tracking-extension.html

Someone got experience in using Aramex Shipping and Tracking Extension?

Got customter with need for that but I am unsure if it will really work bacause:

Official support for 1.7, we got 1.7.0.2
Only one review so far and it isnt a good one

May someone can confirm a working installation on 1.7.0.2?

Comment: `this link is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can confirm running installation on 1.7.0.2!